# Exercise-Induced Asthma Daily Medication Use Short and Long Term Effects?

Tags: lasting-effects-duration, lungs, asthma, asthma-inhalors, exercise-induced-asthma

I have Exercise-Induced Asthma.

I only feel satisfied when I'm either exhausted or when my muscles won't push any further.
In general I don't like medication, I've always at least tried to have my body cure the disease, and at this point I almost never get sick.
But Asthma is a chronic disease so there's no way around it.
I've been given medication, which I have not been using, despite all the headaches, chest pain, and all around unpleasantness.
But I can't reach my limits, and my thing isn't really building muscle, so I need to be able to train. A lot.
I've decided it'd be best to take medication, otherwise I'm not getting anywhere.

What I want to know is whether there are any long term usage secondary effects.
I know from experience there are short term ones - I feel some chest pain while training and if I use it daily (because I have tried it in the past, when I was diagnosed), whenever I stop using it, I feel the effects of Asthma a hell of a lot more. I did it for a week and when I stopped, I found that the next day I felt breathlessness simply getting out of bed.

If I were to use the medication that has been prescribed to me daily, how serious are or how serious can these previously described "short-term symptoms" get? Are there any long-term ones? And if so, how serious are they?

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-) Can you please specify what type of medication are we talking about? If you could give us a generic name that would be great (usually in smaller letters under the commercial name) otherwise the commercial name would be fine as well. Thanks!